# Issue retreiving 'int' object is not iterable error in KERAS

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to run the following code. The following code runs fine on google colab, however on my system it throws an error.  Tensorflow version  installed on my system is is 1.12.0 and keras version is 2.2.4. Help is highly appreciated.

```
def profiler(layer, test_input):
 data_input = test_input
 start = time.time()
 data_input = layer.predict(data_input)
 end = time.time() - start
 milliseconds = end * 1000
 return milliseconds 

def dense_layer(input_dim, dense_size):
    x = tf.keras.layers.Input((input_dim))
    dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(dense_size)(x)
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=x, outputs=dense)
    return model

def process_config(config):
    tokens = config.split(",")
    values = []
    for token in tokens:
        token = token.strip()
        if token.find("-") == -1:
            token = int(token)
            values.append(token)
        else:
            start,end = token.split("-")
            start = int(start.strip())
            end = int(end.strip())
            values = values + list(range(start,end+1))
    return values

def evaluate_dense(input_shapes_range, dense_size_range):
    for input_shape in input_shapes_range:
        for dense_size in dense_size_range:
            to_write = open("dense_data.csv", "a+")
            model = dense_layer(input_shape, dense_size)
            random_input = np.random.randn(1, input_shape)
            running_time = profiler(model, random_input)
            del model

input_size = "2000"
dense_size = "1000, 4096"
input_size_range = process_config(input_size)
dense_size_range = process_config(dense_size)
evaluate_dense(input_size_range, dense_size_range)
```

Error trace

```
  File "C:/Users/Dense-layer.py", line 59, in <module>
    evaluate_dense(input_size_range, dense_size_range)
  File "C:/Users/Dense-layer.py", line 44, in evaluate_dense
    model = dense_layer(input_shape, dense_size)
  File "C:/Users/Dense-layer.py", line 16, in dense_layer
    x = tf.keras.layers.Input((input_dim))
  File "C:\Users\learn\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\input_layer.py", line 229, in Input
    input_tensor=tensor)
  File "C:\Users\learn\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\input_layer.py", line 91, in __init__
    batch_input_shape = (batch_size,) + tuple(input_shape)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Input_shape should be a tuple, and if you pass just one number, you will get this error. As the name of variables, looks like you intended to specify input_dim. So, specify it by the name `tf.keras.layers.Input(input_dim=input_dim)`, otherwise it will consider it as input_shape, which should be tuple.

Comment: Or if you want to specify the shape, use it like: `tf.keras.layers.Input((input_dim,))`

Comment: @Kaveh, Thanks alot its working perfectly fine now. Would you please add this in answer section for the help of wider audience will really appreciate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input_shape` should be a tuple, but `input_dim` is an integer. You have passed `input_dim`, and since you have not specified it by name, it considers it as `input_shape`. So, just specify it by name:

```
tf.keras.layers.Input(input_dim=input_dim)
```

Or if you want to specify the shape, use it like:

```
tf.keras.layers.Input((input_dim,))
```